# Remove blank bullet points (BBCode)

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

Ok so I'm trying to come up with a PHP method that removes blank bullet point lists that I'm doing.

Here is an example I have:

http://rubular.com/r/01ydqcWx3Q

But I can't seem to get it to only grab the [*] that are blank so I can remove them...
This is grabbing the non-blank ones.. so I could put it in the $matches variable below:

```
preg_match('/\[\*\][A-z0-9 ]+/', $body, $matches);
```

But.. I want the $matches to consist of the blank ones so I can just remove them.. or if there is a way to grab everything but the matches to remove except for the [list]..

As you can see, it's grabbing the [ in the [/list] which is not what I want either.
Some of them will have only two blank, three blank, one blank, or ... more...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’d like to match `[*]` with a regex, you have to escape all three characters with backslashes because they are [meta-characters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php). Next, you have to find out if `[*]` is immediately followed by a newline (`\n` or `\r\n`) or end of list (`[/list]`). Then replace it with an empty string.

```
$body = "[list][*]Hydrogen
[*]
[*]Helium
[*]Lithium
[*]
[*]
[*]Beryllium
[*]Boron
[*]Carbon
[*]Nitrogen
[*]
[*]Oxygen
[*][/list]";
$body = preg_replace("/\[\*\](?:\r?\n|(?=\[\/list\]))/", "", $body);
print($body);
```

The output will be:

```
[list][*]Hydrogen
[*]Helium
[*]Lithium
[*]Beryllium
[*]Boron
[*]Carbon
[*]Nitrogen
[*]Oxygen
[/list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to catch strings containing exactly just `[*]`:

```
^\[\*\]$
```

The instruction is then:

```
preg_replace('/^\[\*\]$/', '', $body);
```